# Spring MVC (Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name) after Form Validation error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am encountering a problem with a model attribute that seems to 'disappear' after form validation:

```
public class QuestionController {
    //...
    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String prepareVoterBean(Model model, @RequestParam String voterID) {
        ...
        VoterBean questions = service.getQuestionBean(voterID);
        model.addAttribute("questions", questions);
        return "questionPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@Valid VoterBean questions, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info("QuestionController encountered form errors ");
            return "questionPage";
        }
        return "redirect:/ballot/get";
       }
```

The following is questionPage.jsp where Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name ('questions') occur:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="questions" method="post">
    <fieldset>      
        <legend>Security Questions</legend>
        <p>
            <form:label for="birthDate" path="birthDate" cssErrorClass="error"> <fmt:message key="questions.birthDate"/>: </form:label></br>
            <form:input path="birthDate" /><form:errors path="birthDate"/>
        </p>
        //...
```

questionPage is rendered just fine with a HTTP get request, but when I submit the form wtith validation errors, thereby triggering processSubmit() to return back to questionPage, I have the BindingResult error. I am very confused as to what I am doing wrong, because I questions bean must have been made available to questionPage when it was returned for the first time, but then suddenly the page fails to find the bean after a HTTP POST request with validation error. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `questions` is no longer in the model after you return back to the `questionPage`. You would have to add it again in your `if (result.hasErrors())` block. Model attributes live as long as the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the bean auto-magically back on the map you need to tell Spring to use a bean from the map as binding target by annotating the method parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("questions") VoterBean questions, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("QuestionController encountered form errors ");
        return "questionPage";
    }
    return "redirect:/ballot/get";
   }
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem and adding @ModelAttribute("account") where account in my JSP is:                                 <sf:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" commandName="account">                                              fixed the problem of the error message on validation fail. Now on validation fail, you go back to the original form page, and see the validation error message. Thank you for your help Alfe.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and adding: 
@ModelAttribute("account") 
where account in my JSP is:

```
 <sf:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" commandName="account">
```

fixed the problem of the error message on validation fail. 
Now on validation fail, you go back to the original form page, and see the validation error message. Thank you for your help Alfe.

If interested, this my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/createaccount")
public String createAccount(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("account", new Identity());

    return "createaccount";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doRegister(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("account") Identity account, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("failed");
        return "createaccount";
    }

    //offersService.create(offer);
    System.out.println("success");

    return "accountSuccess";
}
```