# Why is @ModelAttribute not needed here?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and reading "Spring in Action" (which is a good book indeed).
Here I encountered a problem in one of the example in this book that confused me a lot.
In this [example](https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/blob/master/ch02), there are two controllers correspond to two paths respectively. One is DesignTacoController and the other one is OrderController.

During my own trial on this example, I firstly copied OrderController which is a very simple class like below. This piece of code works perfectly when there **is/isn't** error input on web page.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "orderForm";
        }
        log.info("Order submitted: " + order);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

And then I implemented DesignTacoController by myself according to OrderController above

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {

    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
                // adding some ingredients
        );
        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type: types) {
            model.addAttribute(
                    type.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT),
                    filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
        model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
        return "design";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(@Valid Taco design, Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "design";
        }
        log.info("Processing design: " + design);
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

    // more methods ignored
}
```

With this implementation, it works fine when there is no error inputs. However, if I input something against the validator, I will get a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'design' available as request attribute
```

By searching on stackoverflow ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795097/spring-mvc-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-after-f)) and checking the [original example code](https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples/blob/master/ch02/tacos/src/main/java/tacos/web/DesignTacoController.java) on github, I found this class should be implemented like this

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {


    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
            // adding some ingredients
        );

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
        model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
            filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("design", new Taco());
        return "design";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design, Errors errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "design";
        }

        // Save the taco design...
        // We'll do this in chapter 3
        log.info("Processing design: " + design);

        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }
    // more methods ignored
}
```

Here comes my questions,

1. Why does OrderController work with no problem even without using @ModelAttribute annotation?
2. Why do we need @ModelAttribute in DesignTacoController
3. When will addIngredientsToModel be called?
4. Can we merge addIngredientsToModel and showDesignForm?

I think I am lacking of some basic concepts of Spring. Hopefully somebody can help me out with this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm confused, does the order example work when there *are* errors?

Comment: @crizzis Yes. And that is what also confused me. :)

Answer (score 2):

When the @ModelAttribute is used at method level the purpose is to add one or more model attributes to the model. Here adding this

to the model. `model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), filterByType(ingredients, type)); }`

Thing is Spring creates model objects before any request mapping. So **addIngredientsToModel** method will get invoke before any Handler methods.